# SQLAlchemy Create All Table gives a NoReferencedTable Error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am asking fask_sqlalchemy to create table for me. But I am getting a NoReferencedTable Error.

Here is the code for Models:

```
 from db import db


class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'
    ArtistId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(120))

class Album(db.Model):
    ___tablename__ = 'albums'
    AlbumId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Title = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(160), nullable=False)
    ArtistId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('artists.ArtistId'), nullable=False, index=True)

    artist = db.relationship('Artist')
class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    EmployeeId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    LastName = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(20), nullable=False)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(20), nullable=False)
    Title = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(30))
    ReportsTo = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('employees.EmployeeId'), index=True)
    BirthDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    HireDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    Address = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(70))
    City = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    State = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    Country = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    PostalCode = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(10))
    Phone = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(24))
    Fax = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(24))
    Email = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(60))

    parent = db.relationship('Employee', remote_side=[EmployeeId])

class Genre(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'

    GenreId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(120))

class MediaType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'media_types'

    MediaTypeId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(120))


class Playlist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'playlists'

    PlaylistId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(120))

    tracks = db.relationship('Track', secondary='playlist_track')

class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    CustomerId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40), nullable=False)
    LastName = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(20), nullable=False)
    Company = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(80))
    Address = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(70))
    City = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    State = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    Country = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    PostalCode = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(10))
    Phone = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(24))
    Fax = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(24))
    Email = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(60), nullable=False)
    SupportRepId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('employees.EmployeeId'), index=True)

    employee = db.relationship('Employee')


class Invoice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invoices'

    InvoiceId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    CustomerId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('customers.CustomerId'), nullable=False, index=True)
    InvoiceDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    BillingAddress = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(70))
    BillingCity = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    BillingState = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    BillingCountry = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(40))
    BillingPostalCode = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(10))
    Total = db.Column(db.Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)

    customer = db.relationship('Customer')


class Track(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tracks'

    TrackId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(200), nullable=False)
    AlbumId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('albums.AlbumId'), index=True)
    MediaTypeId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('media_types.MediaTypeId'), nullable=False, index=True)
    GenreId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('genres.GenreId'), index=True)
    Composer = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(220))
    Milliseconds = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Bytes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    UnitPrice = db.Column(db.Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)

    album = db.relationship('Album')
    genre = db.relationship('Genre')
    media_type = db.relationship('MediaType')


class InvoiceItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'invoice_items'

    InvoiceLineId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    InvoiceId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('invoices.InvoiceId'), nullable=False, index=True)
    TrackId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('tracks.TrackId'), nullable=False, index=True)
    UnitPrice = db.Column(db.Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)
    Quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    invoice = db.relationship('Invoice')
    track = db.relationship('Track')
```

The errror that I get is

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError
>
> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with
> column 'tracks.AlbumId' could not find table 'albums' with which to
> generate a foreign key to target column 'AlbumId'

The albums table is there and it has AlbumId column as well.
I don't understand this error.

Need some help understanding what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you made a mistake in your Album class. You can't have

```py
db.relationship(...)
```

and

```py
db.Column(db.ForeignKey(...))
```

in the same class.

I think, your Artist and Album classes should look like this:

```py
class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'
    ArtistId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(120))
    Albums = db.relationship('Album', backref="artist"))
    # Instead of 'Albums', you can name it whatever you want.
    # It's just a way to access albums from an artist.

class Album(db.Model):
    ___tablename__ = 'albums'
    AlbumId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Title = db.Column(db.NVARCHAR(160), nullable=False)
    ArtistId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('artists.ArtistId'), nullable=False, index=True)
```

Thanks to this, you will be able to access albums from an artist within the Artiste class and vice-versa.

Thereby, if you want to access albums from an artist, you can do something like this:

```py
artist = Artist(...)
artist.Albums
# It will automatically return albums from this artist
```

and vice-versa.

I suggest you to watch these two videos :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juPQ04_twtA (One-to-Many relationship)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvhoYbjtiKc (Many-to-Many relationship)

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Artist.Albums - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Comment: Albums = db.relationship('Artist', backref="artist")) I think you meant. Albums = db.relationship('Album', backref="artist")).